# Type hint input and output dtype as a TypeVar for a numpy function

Tags: python, numpy, typing, pyright

For example, having two functions

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray
from typing import TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T", bound=np.dtype)
A = TypeVar("A")

def generic_example(value: A) -> A:
    print(type(value))
    return value

def create_from_array(array: NDArray[T]) -> NDArray[T]:
    return array *  np.arange(array.size, dtype=array.dtype).reshape(array.shape)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    array = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1]])
    mylist = generic_example(list(range(19)))
    array = generic_example(array)
    print(create_from_array(array))
```

cause `pyright` error

```
.../numpy_typing_test.py
  .../numpy_typing_test.py:14:30 - error: Could not specialize type "NDArray[ScalarType@NDArray]"
    Type "T@create_from_array" cannot be assigned to type "generic"
      "dtype[Unknown]*" is incompatible with "generic"
  .../numpy_typing_test.py:14:45 - error: Could not specialize type "NDArray[ScalarType@NDArray]"
    Type "T@create_from_array" cannot be assigned to type "generic"
      "dtype[Unknown]*" is incompatible with "generic"
  .../numpy_typing_test.py:15:12 - error: Operator "*" not supported for types "NDArray[Unknown]" and "ndarray[Any, dtype[ScalarType@NDArray]]" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
3 errors, 0 warnings, 0 informations
```

The `TypeVar` for `np.dtype` does not work.

How can I type hint for pyright that the `dtype` of the function output has the same value as some of the inputs or the type that has been given as a input?